# If $X = E[Y | \mathcal{G}]$ and $X^2 = E[Y^2 | \mathcal{G}]$ then $X = Y$ a.s.

Tags: probability

Let be $X$ and $Y$ random variable in $(\Omega , \mathcal{F}, P )$ and $\mathcal{G}$ a $\sigma$- algebra such that  $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$.

I want to prove that:

If

1. $X = E[Y | \mathcal{G}]$
2. $X^2 = E[Y^2 | \mathcal{G}]$

then $$X = Y\hbox{. .} a.s.$$

It is easy see, using the definition,  that $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]$.

Now, observe that

$(X- Y)^2  = X^2 - 2XY + Y^2$

$E[ (X- Y)^2]  = E[X^2] - 2E[XY] + E[Y^2] = 2(E[X^2] - E[XY])$

The ideia is prove that  $E[ (X- Y)^2]= 2(E[X^2] - E[XY]) = 0 $, then it is suficient prove $E[X^2] = E[XY]$

But, using the hipotese, we have

$E[  E[Y^2 | \mathcal{G} ] ] = E[  E[Y | \mathcal{G} ] Y]$

I would like to use the following:

$E[XY |\mathcal{G}  ] = XE[Y |\mathcal{G}  ]$  if X is $\mathcal{G}$-mensurable

to prove that  $E[  E[Y | \mathcal{G} ] Y] = E[  E[Y^2 | \mathcal{G} ]]$ and conclude my proof. Some ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X^2=(\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G}))^2=\mathbb{E}(Y^2|\mathcal{G})$. This implies $$\mathbb{E}((Y-\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G}))^2|\mathcal{G})=\mathbb{E}(Y^2-2Y\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G})+\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G})^2|\mathcal{G})=\mathbb{E}(Y^2|\mathcal{G})-2\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G}).\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G})+\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G})^2=0$$  $$\Rightarrow\mathbb{E}((Y-\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G}))^2|\mathcal{G})=0$$$$\Rightarrow Y=\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G})~a.s.$$

Comment: $E[Y| \mathcal{G}]^2 = E[Y^2 | \mathcal{G}]$ is not clear. I am trying to avoid the variance conditional because I do not know its definitions.

Comment: I have edited my answer so as to bypass the conditional variance argument

Comment: Ok... $E[Y|G]^2=E[Y^2|G]$ is trivial... sorry